# How to stop Item tapped event when long press action in Xamarin.Forms list view

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

when we long press `ListView` it fires both `ItemTapped` and `LongPress` event how to stop `ItemTapped` event when using `LongPress`?? I am using mr.gestures for `LongPress` events.

```
<StackLayout Padding="8,0,8,0" >
    <mr:ListView  x:Name="AllListStack" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" RowHeight="55" LongPressed="Cell_LongPressed"
        Swiped="Cell_Swiped" ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <controls:ExtendedLabel IsStrikeThrough="{Binding Isstrickout}" x:Name="Tasktitle" FontSize="20" Text="{Binding TaskTitle}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                            <!--<Button x:Name="Tasktitle" Text="{Binding TaskTitle}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Button>-->
                            <Label x:Name="TaskTime" IsVisible="{Binding Isvisable}" FontSize="13" Text="{Binding TaskTime}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                            <Image x:Name="imgalram" IsVisible="{Binding Isvisable}" Source="Alarm.png" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="28" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </mr:ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Add some details about the problem you are facing and what you have tried till now.Clear questions with all the necessary points would improves your chances of getting good answers

Comment: in Xamarin forms Listview How can fire item tapped and Lonpress events.

Comment: Did you get any solution? Have tried e.Handled = true or something?  which listview are you using as you inherit it from other namespace?

Comment: I am using mr.gestures Listview